# in wordpress request.open('GET', 'data.json',true); not working. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

Hi i am making a WordPress plugin that can bring the names of products from json file if someone writes products name into the search bar. But i think data.json is not getting by Ajax in WordPress. its path defining syntax error i guess.

`$.getJSON('data.json', function(data)`

following is complete scripting code and it was working fine in PHP website but not in WordPress.:
`jQuery('#search').keyup(function(){

```
var searchField = jQuery('#search').val();
var myExp = RegExp(searchField,"i");
jQuery.getJSON('data.json', function(data){

    var output= '<ul class="SearchResult">';
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val){
        if((val.name.search(myExp) != -1) || (val.category.search(myExp) != -1)){
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';

            output += '<img src="images/'+val.image+'.jpg" alt="sorry for image"/>';

            output += '<p>' + val.category + '</p>';
            output += '</li>';
        }
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#update').html(output);


});
```

});
`

Answer (score 0):

1: the file "data.json" should be in the root of your folder along with the wp-config.php file
2: check your .htaccess if you can access the "data.json" file
3: in wordpress the jquery version, you only can use jQuery instead of $ , so i can see you are using $("#update") , change it to jQuery("#update")

```
    jQuery('#update').html(output);
```

Comment: 1: The "data.json" file is into my custom-plugins folder where the main file is and wp-config.php is into wp-includes. should i copy wp-config.php file and paste it into my plugin's folder? 
2: I did not get the .htaccess thing it might be new for me.
3: I replaced All $ characters with jQuery but the problem persists.
@Luis Cardenas